# Getting cartesian product of specified lists from multiple lists

Tags: python

Please don't mind my newbie style of writing the code.... Am just at beginner stage:: a more efficient correction is welcome.

Step 1: I have multiple list like this:

```
aaa = "abcd"
bbb = "efgh"
ccc = "ijkl"
ddd = "mnop"
eee = "qrst"
no1 = "1234"
no2 = "3456"
no3 = "7890"

listpack = [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, no1, no2, no3]
```

Step 2: Generate random alphabets and numbers from those lists

```
all_list = (aaa+bbb+ccc+ddd+eee+no1+no2+no3) 
randgen = random.sample(all_list, k=10) #print(randgen)#: aem31kgcs9
```

ISSUE #Step 3: Get the cartesan product of only the list whose element startswith each character in randgen(step 2 above) #This is what i've tried

```
newlist=[]
for i in origin:
    for x in diclist:
        if x.startswith(i):
            newlist.append([x]) 

for xx in itertools.product(newlist):
    print(xx)
```

but it prints only the elements and also on separate line

I want to get the cartesian product of newlist

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you should assign the value instead of printing it, if you are planning to use it further in your code.

Comment: you may want to skip on the '#' at the start of each line as it's already well-readable because of the use of newline characters by you.

Answer (score 2):

`randgen=['f', 'q', '8', 'i', 's', '3', 'a', 'k', 'o', '1']`
You can use list for appending

```py
newlist=[]
for i in randgen:
    for x in listpack:
        if x.startswith(i):
            newlist.append(x)

newlist
```

Output:
`['qrst', 'ijkl', '3456', 'abcd', '1234']`

Comment: You can use list comprehension also `newlist=[x for x in listpack  for i in randgen if x.startswith(i)]`

Comment: Yeah so you need variable name correct. Use dictionary if you are allowed to use it or else make if else condition for getting variable name by mapping value to it's variable name string.